# Application subclass gets deleted on "Android Tools"->Export

Tags: eclipse, export, package, android

hello fellow android programmers,
I'm constantly running into the same problem over and over again and I can't figure it out, so I thought I'd ask my question here.

To implement `ACRA` (Application Crash Reporting for Android @ http://code.google.com/p/acra) I have to create a `subclass` of `android.Application` and instantiate ACRA.

I create this subclass from within the Manifest.xml editor by clicking on the left upper field "Name" in the "Application" tab. A window pops up where I'm asked to give a proper name to the new class and it is created in the `/gen` folder (only the `R.java` is also in this folder) and the needed attribute `android:name` is set in the `<application/>` tag automatically.

This works like a charm and all is good if I run my application from within the IDE on the emulator or on my debugging device... **BUT**, *as soon as I want to export the whole package (doesn't mind if "signed" or "unsigned") the previous created `android.Application subclass` is removed from the `/gen` folder (must be from compiling), the APK gets saved and no error shows up. Until one tries to install and run the application - this will fail due to the lack of this unlucky subclass...*

**What is wrong? Where do I have to place this subclass other then in the `/gen` folder? Does anybody else run into the same problem?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should not go into the `/gen` directory; that directory is for code that is automatically generated by the Android compiler during builds. The `Application` class you're creating is application code, not auto-generated code. Don't be confused by the fact that ADT is doing you a favor by "generating" it for you from the GUI editor; that's not the same thing as the compiler building the code automatically for every build.

Your `Application` class should go in the same place as all your other app code (`Activity` subclasses, etc), namely `/src` (or `/source` or whatever depending on how you set up your project).

Comment: thanks a lot, I just placed my Application class in the /src package and all went well!